# Only allow Nancy to return json or Xml and 406 when accept header is html

Tags: http, nancy, content-negotiation

I'm writing a Nancy endpoint and I want to do something that I think should be really simple. I want to support returning the content in either json or xml but when html or any other type is requested to return a 406 Not supported. I can easily force either XML or JSON only, and I guess I could do and if (accept is html) return 406  but I would assume that there is some support for this in the content Negotiation support.

Can anybody shed any light?

Answer (score 1):

Implement your own IResponseProcessor, Nancy will pick it up and hook in the engine.

```
public sealed class NoJsonOrXmlProcessor : IResponseProcessor
    {
        public ProcessorMatch CanProcess(MediaRange requestedMediaRange, dynamic model, NancyContext context)
        {
            if (requestedMediaRange.Matches("application/json") || requestedMediaRange.Matches("aaplication/xml"))
            {
                //pass on, so the real processors can handle
                return new ProcessorMatch{ModelResult = MatchResult.NoMatch, RequestedContentTypeResult = MatchResult.NoMatch};
            }
            return new ProcessorMatch{ModelResult = MatchResult.ExactMatch, RequestedContentTypeResult = MatchResult.ExactMatch};
        }

        public Response Process(MediaRange requestedMediaRange, dynamic model, NancyContext context)
        {
            return new Response{StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.NotAcceptable};
        }

        public IEnumerable<Tuple<string, MediaRange>> ExtensionMappings { get; private set; }
    }
```

Comment: You may need to override `NancyInternalConfiguration` with your own collection of requestprocessors to ensure that this is first.

Answer (score 1):

We avoided the use of `ResponseProcessor` for the whole reason that the request was still being run all the way through our authentication layer, domain layer, etc. We wanted a way to quickly kill the request as soon as possible.

What we ended up doing was performing the check inside our own `Boostrapper`

```cs
public class Boostrapper : DefaultNancyBootstrapper
{
    protected override void RequestStartup(TinyIoCContainer requestContainer, IPipelines pipelines, NancyContext context)
    {
        base.RequestStartup(requestContainer, pipelines, context);

        pipelines.BeforeRequest += nancyContext =>
        {
            RequestHeaders headers = nancyContext.Request.Headers
            if (!IsAcceptHeadersAllowed(headers.Accept))
            {
                return new Response() {StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.NotAcceptable};
            }
            return null;
         }
    }

    private bool IsAcceptHeadersAllowed(IEnumerable<Tuple<string, decimal>> acceptTypes)
    {
        return acceptTypes.Any(tuple =>
        {
            var accept = new MediaRange(tuple.Item1);
            return accept.Matches("application/json") || accept.Matches("application/xml");
        });
    }
}
```